# How to set up and use Google Test (as a submodule) with CMake

Tags: git, cmake, qt-creator, googletest, xunit

I have cloned the Google Test repo from GitHub into a personal repository and then added it as a submodule into my main project (using git).

I want to be able to use this submodule in my main project by using `#include "gtest/gtest.h"`

The location of gtest in my file structure is:

```
C:\GIT\MyProj\Externals\ABCD\tests\externals\UnitTests\externals\GoogleTest\googletest\include\gtest
```

`UnitTests` is a submodule, and `GoogleTest` is a submodule inside of that submodule.

My attempt at this is:

```
function(MyProjTestSetup)

    #initiaise stuff
    set(EXTERNAL_NAME Gtest)
    include(ExternalProject)
    set(GTEST_FORCE_SHARED_CRT ON)
    set(GTEST_DISABLE_PTHREADS OFF)

    if(MINGW)
        set(GTEST_DISABLE_PTHREADS ON)
    endif()

    if(WIN32)
        set(WINDOWS_CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG:PATH=DebugLibs
        -DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE:PATH=ReleaseLibs
        )
    else(WIN32)
        set(WINDOWS_CMAKE_ARGS )
    endif(WIN32)

    set(${EXTERNAL_NAME}_PROJECT ${PROJECT_NAME}_${EXTERNAL_NAME})

    #------------build Gtest----------------------
    #---------------------------------------------
    ExternalProject_Add(Gtest
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXTERNAL_NAME}
        CMAKE_ARGS
        ${WINDOWS_CMAKE_ARGS}
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${MSVC_COMPILER_DEFS}
        -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=${GTEST_FORCE_SHARED_CRT}
        -Dgtest_disable_pthreads=${GTEST_DISABLE_PTHREADS}
        -DBUILD_GTEST=ON
        -DBUILD_GMOCK=OFF
        PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        # Disable install step
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1
        )

    # -----------Specify include dir--------------
    #---------------------------------------------
    set(${EXTERNAL_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/tests/externals/UnitTests/externals/GoogleTest/googletest/include
        )

    include_directories(${${EXTERNAL_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    # ---------Specify link libraries-------------
    #---------------------------------------------
    set(${EXTERNAL_NAME}_LIBRARIES
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
        )


endfunction()
```

This gives the error:

```
NMAKE:-1: error: U1073: don't know how to make '\gtest.lib'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check that you have appropriate `include_directories()` call. If it is, including the header should work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added in that function and it can now include the headers, however, I now get a new, even more, confusing error.

Comment: Is this error occure when build google test? Or when you build your executable? How `${EXTERNAL_NAME}_LIBRARIES` variable is used? (According to the name, the variable should contain libraries, but it is set to directory). It is difficult to fix problems in **incomplete code**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ${EXTERNAL_NAME}_LIBRARIES is not used, I have just copied this layout from another project, I am new to CMAKE. You are right, it is an incomplete code. I was hoping for a guide to set up gtest as a local external with cmake.

Comment: Take a look this project template: https://github.com/akanmuratcimen/cmakecppboilerplate